# Using ImportHTML to locate one table cell

Tags: google-sheets

I have a list of people who all have an ID that is used by www.pdga.com to make a player rating (for example, my PDGA Number is 8849, and the page showing my player rating is [here](http://www.pdga.com/player-stats?PDGANum=8849&year=2009)).

My spreadsheet contains a list of players' PDGANum values. I want to scrape the PDGA Player Rating for each player from the player-stats page and put it in a cell adjacent to the player name and PDGA Number.

I can use ImportHtml to import the table on an individual page:

```
=ImportHtml("http://www.pdga.com/player-stats?PDGANum=8849&year=2009", "table",D23)
```

This then creates a matrix of =CONTINUE() calls to pad out the table in the sheet.

I can use cell references to change the URL parameter "PDGANum" to get any players' ratings. However, using ImportHTML builds the whole table in the spreadsheet. The actual cell I want is in col 2, row 2.

What I want is to scrape just one cell of the HTML table into my Google spreadsheet. It would seem that I could do something like:

```
=CONTINUE(ImportHtml("http://www.pdga.com/player-stats?PDGANum="&B2&"&year=2009", "table",B1),2,2)
```

but it doesn't work!

Answer (score 0):

You seem to be using old Google Sheets and connecting to a site that requires password access, so UNTESTED but you might try:

```
=index(ImportHtml("http://www.pdga.com/player-stats?PDGANum=8849&year=2009", "table"),2,2)
```